# Whenever a failover occurs, either manually or automatically Immediately blocking problem occurs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, failover, blocking

I have a table **log_table**, and I have two stored procedures: **insert_sp** for inserting log entries into the table, and **update_sp** for performing update operations.

I have a SQL Server failover cluster with two nodes. Whenever a failover occurs, either manually or automatically, the log_table gets blocked for 30-50 minutes.

Why this kind of problem occurs on the only failover except failover there is no any blocking on this table? How can I intervene to end the blocking? What can I do to prevent it from happening again?

Here is the **update_sp** stored procedure:

```
    @ID varchar(32),
    @Resp varchar(max),
    @RespDate datetime,
    @ServTime float = null
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[log_table]
    SET Resp = @Resp,
        RespDate = @RespDate,
        ServTime = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,RequestDate,@RespDate)
    WHERE
        ID = @ID AND
        RecordTime > DATEADD(HOUR, -1 , GETDATE())  
END
```

Here is the **insert_sp** stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_sp]
    @ID varchar(32)
    @Resp varchar(max),
    @RequestDate datetime,
    @RespDate datetime,
    @ServTime float=null,
    @TranCode varchar(64) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[log_table] ([ID], [Resp], [RequestDate],[RespDate], [ServTime], TranCode)
     VALUES (@ID, @Resp, @RequestDate, @RespDate, @ServTime, @TranCode)
END
```

Note: I'm using SQL Server 2019 Enterprise (CU19)

I tried kill blocking SPID but every time occurs another id (no success)
I did a recompile for these 2 stored procedures (no success)
I tried to alter update_sp without altering operation, but it is already on blocking.(no success)

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the blocking? What's the blocking transaction? what's its state? what's the blocked transaction?